# Why PHPStan can't find the class installation by pear?

Tags: php, phpstan

PHPStan can't find the classes I installed with pear.
Why? How can I fix it?

## Steps

1. Run: `pear install HTTP_Request2-2.5.1`
2. Check: `pear config-get php_dir`

```
/usr/share/pear
```

3. Check: `php -i | grep include_path`

```
include_path => .:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php => .:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php
```

4. Check: `ls -l /usr/share/pear/HTTP/Request2.php`

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 36102  Aug 19 11:38 /usr/share/pear/HTTP/Request2.php
```

5. Write `test.php`

```php
<?php

require_once 'HTTP/Request2.php';

$request = new \HTTP_Request2("http://example.com");
```

6. Run `phpstan analyze test.php`

```
 ------ --------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  Line   test.php                                                             
 ------ --------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  5      Instantiated class HTTP_Request2 not found.                          
          Learn more at https://phpstan.org/user-guide/discovering-symbols   
 ------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the PEAR library path using `phpstan.neon` config file.

```
parameters:
    scanDirectories:
        - /usr/share/pear
    level: 5
```

```
$ phpstan analyze -c path/to/phpstan.neon test.php
```

Since your PEAR library `HTTP_Request2` has not been installed via composer, [PHPStan doesn't aware where it's from](https://phpstan.org/user-guide/discovering-symbols#third-party-code-outside-of-composer-dependencies).

It seems PHPStan doesn't care `include_path` [intentionally](https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan/issues/1728).